# how to Mock handler in kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, unit-testing, mockito, handler

```
   public void myTesting(){
    System.out.println("testing before ");
    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("test");
        }
    }, 100);
    System.out.println("testing after ");

}
```

I am trying to mock the above handler code on kotlin using slot function to return run() function

here are my changes

```
    mockkStatic(Looper::class)
    mockkStatic(Runnable::class)
    val looper = mockk<Looper>{
        every {
            thread
        } returns Thread.currentThread()
    }

    every {
        Looper.getMainLooper()
    } returns looper

    val Handler = mockk<Handler>(relaxed = true)

    every {
        Handler.postDelayed(capture(slotrunnable) ,100)
    } answers  {
        true
    }

    slotrunnable.captured.run()

    Manager.myTesting()
```

when i run the test case i am getting
lateinit property captured has not been initialized slot

Comment: is there any way to solve this issue?  i am a newbie in Unit testing

Comment: Where does the lateinit error come from? I don't see such a property in the code you've posted

Comment: @Jorn the Mockk library has a `CapturingSlot` class with a `captured` property which is lateinit.

Comment: sorry missout val slotRunnable = slot<Runnable>() at setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your system-under-test creates a new Handler:

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(...
```

But your unit test code uses `every` only for a specific mock handler:

```
val Handler = mockk<Handler>(relaxed = true)

    every {
        Handler.postDelayed(capture(slotrunnable) ,100)
```

So this will only work for that specific mock object. You may have been misled by naming your object with a capital initial letter, the same name as the class. Don't do that. If you had named it `handler` instead of `Handler`, you would then have noticed that your `every` will affect only that method and not the whole class.

You should pass a Handler object to your method (dependency injection) instead of creating it inside the method. Then your unit test can pass the mock object to your method under test.

Comment: Using Slot and Mock constructor works too. thanks for the info